# How to add admob with webview

Tags: android, webview, admob

This webviews already blocks popups it only accept particular url here it is www.google.com other urls will not open on webview i have tried some methods to implement admob but the application didnot work is thier anyway to use admob in the bottom of the app i have tryed this and its not working 
[Getting admob and webview working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183894/getting-admob-and-webview-working-together)

```
package zippy.zippytest;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.JsPromptResult;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private  WebView mWebview1;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayout layoutProgress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebview1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        layoutProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProgress);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override


            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https://www\\.google\\.com/*", Pattern.MULTILINE);


                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

                if (matcher.find()) {


                    return false;

                }

                return true;

            }


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }

            public void but(View v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        });


            }
        });*/





        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));
               String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                String name=""+id+".torrent";
                final String[] separated = url.split("/"); final String myFile = separated[separated.length - 1];

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,name);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
                intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        if(isOnline()) {
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        } else {
            String summary = "<html><body><font color='red'>No Internet Connection</font></body></html>";
            webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
            toast("No Internet Connection.");
        }
    }
    private void toast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
    }
    public void but(View v){

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.googel.com/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be displaying ads within your own WebView. You should be using the AdMob AdView and displaying your ads via it. Place the AdView below your WebView in the layout.

Comment: i have already tried it but its not working will you please explain it

Comment: Add an AdView to your layout below your WebView.

Comment: " <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="MYIDMYIDMYID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >"

Comment: is that is the one?

Comment: do i need to import any additional library for this?

Comment: That is the correct layout config. You need to Google Play Ads library.

Comment: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList it gives me this error

Comment: Then you haven't added the Google Ads library to your project correctly.

Comment: how can i add that?

Comment: You should add it to your Gradle/Maven dependencies.

Comment: i think i have already done it when the app runs it gives me adsize is missing in xml